# Implementing Python Protocols using both regular methods and class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Assume I have two classes `Foo1` and `Foo2` that implement a method `bar()`:

- In `Foo1`, `bar()` is a regular method
- In `Foo2`, `bar()` is a `@classmethod`

```py
class Foo1:

    def bar(self) -> None:
        print("foo1.bar")


class Foo2:

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls) -> None:
        print("Foo2.bar")
```

Now assume I have a function that accepts a list of "anything that has a `bar()` method" and calls it:

```py
def foreach_foo_call_bar(foos):
    for foo in foos:
        foo.bar()
```

Calling this function works fine during runtime:

```py
foreach_foo_call_bar([Foo1(), Foo2])
```

as both `Foo1()` and `Foo2` has a `bar()` method.

However, how can I properly add type hints to `foreach_foo_call_bar()`?

I tried creating a [PEP544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#using-protocols) `Protocol` called `SupportsBar`:

```py
class SupportsBar(Protocol):

    def bar(self) -> None:
        pass
```

and annotating like so:

```py
def foreach_foo_call_bar(foos: Iterable[SupportsBar]):
   ...
```

But mypy says:

```
List item 1 has incompatible type "Type[Foo2]"; expected "SupportsBar"
```

Any idea how to make this properly annotated?

Answer (score 10):

The issue appears to be that `Protocol` is specifically checking if an *instance*  method is supported, not just that an attribute of the correct name exists. In the case of `Foo2`, that means the metaclass needs an instance method named `bar`; the following seems to behave as expected and type-checks.

```
# Define a metaclass that provides an instance method bar for its instances.
# A metaclass instance method is almost equivalent to a class method.
class Barrable(type):
    def bar(cls) -> None:
        print(cls.__name__ + ".bar")


class Foo1:
    def bar(self) -> None:
        print("foo1.bar")


class Foo2(metaclass=Barrable):
    pass


class SupportsBar(Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> None:
        pass


def foreach_foo_call_bar(foos: Iterable[SupportsBar]):
    for foo in foos:
        foo.bar()
```

I won't claim that converting a class method to a metaclass instance method is a good workaround (in fact, it does nothing for static methods), but it points to this being a fundamental limitation of `Protocol` that it doesn't handle arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Perhaps getting ahead of myself, but if you like this answer, you don't necessarily have to award it the bounty. I am not sure what the correct way to assert that a particular attribute lookup will succeed, only that `Protocol` is not the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While it looks like this would work, I don't think anyone should be doing this to solve this issue (as you said). I will leave this question unanswered for now in the hopes that a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 8):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4536) with mypy.  The BFDL hisself even [acknowledged](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4536#issuecomment-395631269) it as incorrect behavior precisely 2 years before @MatanRubin asked this question.  It remains unresolved, but was recently (November 2019) marked as high priority so hopefully the example provided here will no longer generate a false positive soon.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that issue, looks like exactly the issue I described. Let's hope this gets fixed soon!

Comment: @Matan I was even more surprised that in the context of your example `foo2: SupportsBar = Foo2` fails to type check properly!

Answer (score 4):

The second item in the list of `foos`, `Foo2` is a class not an instance such as `Foo1()`. This needs to be specified by wrapping around `Type`:

```
def foreach_foo_call_bar(
        foos: Iterable[Union[SupportsBar,
                             Type[SupportsBar]]]):
    # ...
```

You can also do this without the use of a `Protocol`:

```
def foreach_foo_call_bar(
        foos: Iterable[Union[Foo1,
                             Type[Foo2]]]):
    # ...
```

Comment: I thought about that, but that seems cumbersome. I'm looking for a way to define a type based on its available methods, regardless of these being class methods or instance methods. This is classic duck-typing - I don't care what the object is, I just care that it has a method called `bar()`.  

IOW, I'm trying to find a way to let the type checker know that something "quacks like a duck", without caring about it being a class or an instance. If during runtime I can call `bar()` on that object, then the type I'm looking for should satisfy the type checker, without the need to for a union.